# Данный пользователь в виджете сообщества ВКонтакте

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Читал документацию. Вроде все ясно: берем id зашедшего в группу юзера, потом в icon_id виджета вставляем id+id пользователя. Но вот проблема: как узнать кто именно зашел в группу? Вот как здесь: https://vk.com/club160188840. Сделал в предлагаемом вк конструкторе виджетов

Answer (score 0):

Вот пожалуйста. Сам еле нашел.. 
https://toster.ru/q/510635

Ну и соответственно для JS код:

```js
VK.callMethod('showAppWidgetPreviewBox', 'text', 'var user=API.users.get({"user_ids": [Args.uid]});  return { "title": user[0].first_name+" Привет2", "text": "Текст цитаты" };');
```